# jQuery animate a floating div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-float

I'm trying to create a fade-in animation for a div. The idea is to move div from right to left and fade-in. Because of the layout, the div is floated right above a certain window width (i.e. 501px) and left below (500px).

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="animated"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width:501px)
{
    #animated {
        float:right;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:500px) 
{
    #animated {
        float:left;
    }
}
```

When div is floated right everything works fine, but when floating property is set to left the movement stops working. How can I change my script to achieve the movement with a ***unique*** code, independently from floating property and CSS breaking points? Thanks in advance.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3L93z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to get the browser window width and then do a conditional check on that for your animation.

Javascript:

```
// Returns float of animated window based on CSS values
var float = $('#animated').css('float');

if (float == 'right') {
    $('#animated').css("margin-right", '10%').animate({
        "margin-right": "-=10%",
        opacity: 1
    }, 2000, 'swing');
} else {
    $('#animated').css("margin-left", '10%').animate({
        "margin-left": "-=10%",
        opacity: 1
    }, 2000, 'swing');
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/3L93z/3/

Comment: I see your point, but my goal is to create a unique code for both animations, which not depends from window width. Detecting window width into the script binds the script to CSS. If I change CSS breaking point, I must change script too. This is why I would like to create a unique code, which not depends on CSS properties (i.e. window width or floating property).

Comment: ok have edited it to use `float` css property to keep the constraint only in the CSS.